# Can all of the first and second differences of a Costas array be at least 3 in magnitude?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

A Costas array $\pi = d_1 d_2 \ldots d_n$ (one-line form) of order $n$ is a permutation $\pi \in S_n$ such that the $n-r$ differences

$d_{r+1} - d_{1} , d_{r+2} - d_{2} , \ldots , d_n - d_{n-r}$

are distinct for each $r$ , $1 \leq r \leq n-1$.

Find an example of a Costas array $\pi$ for some $n$ such that the $2n-3$ inequalities

$|d_2 - d_1| , |d_3 - d_2| , \ldots , |d_n - d_{n-1}| \geq 3$

and

$|d_3 - d_1| , |d_4 - d_2| , \ldots , |d_n - d_{n-2}| \geq 3$

hold or else prove that no such permutation exists.

Remarks:  No such Costas arrays have been found using Beard's database of Costas arrays out to order $1030$ (the database is available at https://ieee-dataport.org/open-access/costas-arrays-and-enumeration-order-1030 and is exhaustive out to order $29$.)  Costas arrays are known to exist for infinitely many (but not all) orders by constructions involving the infinitude of primes.

Comment: You said $n=11$ doesn't work. What am I missing here: 1 4 7 10 2 5 8 11 3 6 9?

Comment: Ach!  I found a flaw in my verification code.  Todor Markov your example does work.

I am also interested in the same question for the restricted class of permutations known as Costas arrays.  I will make the appropriate edits.  Thank you.